# How TTY "input speed" differs from "output speed"?

Tags: tty, termios

There are two commands for setting "speed" - `cfsetospeed` and `cfsetispeed`.

But why only one "speed" is shown by `stty`?

According to `bits/termios.h`, `c_ispeed` and `c_ospeed` are "input speed" and "output speed".

I tried to set `B4800` to "input speed" and "B57600" to "output speed", and vice versa at the other
end of serial channel. But data is corrupted. Why there are two separate speeds if it is impossible to set
them separately?

`stty` shows the speed which was set by `cfsetospeed` or `cfsetispeed` - whichever was called last.

Besides, `B0` setting takes effect only with `cfsetospeed`. Is it documented somewhere?
Moreover, while `B0` is set, I can receive and transmit data with whatever speed was
active before `B0` was set. Is it documented somewhere? Is it undefined behavior or it is in POSIX?

**EDIT:**

I conducted the same tests on ordinary serial port (i.e., no usb) and obtained the following curious difference with usb serial port:
Ordinary serial port uses 9600 "speed" if we set `B0`, whereas
usb serial port uses whatever speed was selected before `B0` was set.

(OS: Linux)

Answer (score 1):

> Why there are two separate speeds if it is impossible to set them separately?

Some (older) UARTs (e.g. the ubiquitous 8250 and its successors) actually have a crystal input for the transmitter and another clock input for the receiver.   Hence the input baudrate can be different from the output baudrate on such  UARTs.
But most (if not all) boards feed the transmit clock to the receive clock to *negate* this feature (e.g. the typical 8250/[165x0 datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/pc16550d.pdf) will show the RCLK input driven by the BAUDOUT output).
The separate termios speed elements simply reflects this obscure hardware capability (that is rarely actually available).

Also most UARTs (that are not 8250-based) in SoCs have a common clock input for transmit and receive, so the baudrate setting has to apply to both.
So specifying  "separate" baudrates is typically a useless configuration.

> Besides, B0 setting takes effect only with cfsetospeed. Is it documented somewhere?

Code is the documentation.
Most serial port drivers call **uart_get_baud_rate()** in [drivers/tty/serial/serial_core.c](https://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/tty/serial/serial_core.c#L387) to decode the baudrate settings from the termios structure.

```
/**
 *  uart_get_baud_rate - return baud rate for a particular port
 *  @port: uart_port structure describing the port in question.
 *  @termios: desired termios settings.
 *  @old: old termios (or NULL)
 *  @min: minimum acceptable baud rate
 *  @max: maximum acceptable baud rate
 *
 *  Decode the termios structure into a numeric baud rate,
 *  taking account of the magic 38400 baud rate (with spd_*
 *  flags), and mapping the %B0 rate to 9600 baud.
 *
 *  If the new baud rate is invalid, try the old termios setting.
 *  If it's still invalid, we try 9600 baud.
 *
 *  Update the @termios structure to reflect the baud rate
 *  we're actually going to be using. Don't do this for the case
 *  where B0 is requested ("hang up").
 */
```

Note the special handling mentioned for `B0`.

> I conducted the same tests on ordinary serial port (i.e., no usb) and obtained the following curious difference with usb serial port:...

The list of drivers that use **uart_get_baud_rate()** does not seem to include any USB serial port adapters:  https://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/ident/uart_get_baud_rate

You may have to inspect the driver for your specific USB serial port adapter for its handling of the termios baudrate specifers.